# How to find a value in another sheet and get min and max values from adjustment columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA macro and need some experts help on meeting the below requirement.

I got a workbook containing 2 sheets called 'Data' and 'Stats'.

'Data' contains the values as below

[image]

'Stats' contains the values as below

[image]

On click on the button, I would like to do the below

1. Get the values in column A in 'Stats' sheet
2. Find all the matching rows in 'Data' Sheet
3. Find the smallest start time and put that in 'Stats' sheet against the stage value
4. Find the biggest end time and that in 'Stats' sheet against the stage value

Final output would be like below

[image]

Note: I do not have the MINIFS or MAXIFS in my installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase you dont have `MINIFS` and `MAXIFS` you can use array formulas like so:

`={MIN(IF(Stats!A1=Data!$A$1:$A$1000,Data!$C$1:$C$1000))}`

and

`={MAX(IF(Stats!A1=Data!$A$1:$A$1000,Data!$B$1:$B$1000))}`

The `{}` indicates, that this is a Array-Formula. Enter with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried and I am getting 00:00:00.  Can you explain the arguments how is that exactly finds and get the minimum/maximum value?

Comment: I managed to make some progress.  If I harcode the search string as this `=MIN(IF((Data!C2:C9="A1"),Data!A2:A9,""))` then I am getting the minimum value.  But how should I get the value from 'Stats' tab instead of hardcoding?

Comment: Instead of `=MIN(IF((Data!C2:C9="A1"),Data!A2:A9,""))` use `=MIN(IF((Data!C2:C9=A1),Data!A2:A9,""))`. That is Basically the same answer I gave you except I used `Stats!A1` instead of `A1`

Comment: I am getting the same 00:00:00.  When i put `A1` or `Stats!A1`it gets the value 'Stage' and trying to match and hence it is returning no value.

Comment: Sorry, you should put A2, not A1... A1 references to the header

Answer (score 1):

No VBA needed.

Just use in your `Stats` worksheet the following formula for `Start`:

```
=MINIFS(Data!A:A,Data!C:C,Stats!A:A)
```

and the following for `End`:

```
=MAXIFS(Data!B:B,Data!C:C,Stats!A:A)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do not have MINIFS and MAXIFS in my installation of MS Excel.

Comment: @Malaiselvan Then see MG92's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, the VBA solution, too. It will be very fast, using arrays, processing everything in memory and dropping the result at once:

```
Sub BringStats()
 Dim shD As Worksheet, shS As Worksheet, lastRD As Long, lastRS As Long
 Dim arrD, arrS, i As Long, k As Long, dict As Object, El As Variant
 
 Set shD = Worksheets("Data")
 Set shS = Worksheets("Stats")
 lastRD = shD.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastRS = shS.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arrD = shD.Range("A2:C" & lastRD).Value
 arrS = shS.Range("A2:C" & lastRS).Value
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
 'load the dictionary with unique keys and all corresponding date in a string, as item
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrD)
    If Not dict.Exists(arrD(i, 3)) Then
        dict.Add arrD(i, 3), CDate(arrD(i, 1)) & ";" & CDate(arrD(i, 2))
    Else
        dict(arrD(i, 3)) = dict(arrD(i, 3)) & "|" & CDate(arrD(i, 1)) & ";" & CDate(arrD(i, 2))
    End If
 Next
 
 Dim arr As Variant, minTime As Date, minPos As Long
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrS)
    If dict.Exists(arrS(i, 1)) Then
        arr = Split(dict(arrS(i, 1)), "|") 'extract each pair of time stamps
        If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
            For Each El In arr 'extract the element containing minimum time
                If minTime = 0 Then
                    minTime = TimeValue(Split(El, ";")(0)): minPos = k
                Else
                    If TimeValue(Split(El, ";")(0)) < minTime Then minTime = TimeValue(Split(El, ";")(0)): minPos = k
                End If
                k = k + 1
            Next
            arrS(i, 2) = Split(arr(minPos), ";")(0): arrS(i, 3) = Split(arr(minPos), ";")(1) 'load the array with the minimum time correspondent values
        Else
            arrS(i, 2) = Split(dict(arrS(i, 1)), ";")(0): arrS(i, 3) = Split(dict(arrS(i, 1)), ";")(1)'loading the array in case of only one occurrence
        End If
    End If
    minPos = 0: minTime = 0: k = 0 'reinitialize the used variables
 Next i
 'drop the processed array at once
 shS.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrS), UBound(arrS, 2)).Value = arrS
End Sub
```

There can be a lot of the same 'stage' occurrences...